# Substiitute of dev_appserver.py of Google App Engine [Need to upgrade to FLEXIBLE environment]

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, flask-restful, app-engine-flexible

I have a `Flask-restful API(micro-service)` written in python 2.7 using Google Cloud STANDARD environment, and `dev_appserver.py(gcloud sdk)` helps to run it locally.

Now, I plan to do three things:

1. Upgrade the code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5
2. Google Cloud STANDARD environment to Google cloud FLEXIBLE environment
   **Question:** but standard environment uses AppEngine library and methods, that don't work in flexible environment, so, can Google Cloud Client libraries solve the purpose?
3. Run locally and test the micro-service
   **Question:** Please give suggestions to replace `dev_appserver.py`

Comment: tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. There are a lot of differences between the environments. A lot of methods and libs from standard won't work in flex.

   See here for more info:

   - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments
   - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users
   - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating
3. You can't use `dev_appserver.py` in flex environment. You will need to run Flask the regular way. e.g (locally) `FLASK_APP=main.py FLASK_DEBUG=1 python -m flask run --port 8080`