# python virtualenv No module error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I am on Mac OS and developing for  google cloud platform.
I have created vitualenv - `virtualenv xyz`.
I activated using - source xyz/bin/activate
Then, I installed the pkg I needed - `pip install python-dateutil`
When I do `pip list`, I do see the `python-dateutil` is there
But when i run my service using `dev_appserver.py .` and try to make a post request. I get the `ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser`

Questions: In my `appengine_config.py`, I have `vendor.add('lib')` but the packages are installed under `my_project-> xyz -> lib -> python2.7 -> site-packages -> dateutil`. How does my app knows where to look for packages?

Second question: When I am ready to deploy to production, how do I deploy the packages. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.  Is that enough for prod server to know what packages to use. Do I need `lib` folder under my_project? I am confused about how packages get referred in virtualenv and in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the instructions for installing dependencing for the [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) with those for the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries). Related: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

You're using `dev_appserver.py` so I assume your app is a standard environment one, in which case you need to install the library *into your app* (note the `-t lib` arguments), not on the system/venv. Assuming you execute from your app's dir:

```
pip install python-dateutil -t lib
```

Comment: So if I am using standard environment, how do I have a fresh environment with no packages installed, each time I start a new project. Basically same thing as virtualenv.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I get your question. In stdenv you always start with the sandbox-provided packages (and on the your local system by the SDK). Anything extra needs to be added to your app.

Comment: In my dev environment, lets say i am working on project 1 and did `pip install python-dateutil`. I am guessing this gets installed in my global env. And I switch to project 2 (still in my dev) and it will have access to global packages but I don't want to refer python-dateutil in project 2. How do I keep separate copies of python packages for each project.

Comment: What you install in the venv is irellevant for standard apps. Only what's installed in each app's `lib` dir is relevant (which is uploaded to GAE together with your app). So you only install in each app's dir what that particular app needs.