# How to use Python 3 with Google App Engine's Local Development Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I've got a local Python application configured with

```
runtime: python
```

in it's `app.yaml` file. When starting the local development server with

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

all is fine.

Since GAE's Local Development Server uses Python2.7 by default, I now want to make use of Python3.x instead. According to Google's documentation, we have to use the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime). Thus I'm changing `app.yaml` to:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Now `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` spits out:

```
Under dev_appserver, runtime:python is not supported for Flexible environment.
```

The problem can be reproduced with [Google's Hello World application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/hello_world) that uses the flexible environment as well.

So locally we can't use Python3? How can we then run my Python3 code locally before uploading it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) is applicable to the **first generation** standard environment apps only.

For running locally flexible env apps see [Running locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally):

> You run your application locally with the native development tools
>   that you usually use.
>
> For example, you can usually run a Flask application with Flask's
>   development server using:
>
> ```
> python main.py
> ```
>
> Django applications can be started using:
>
> ```
> python manage.py runserver
> ```

Related: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

**Update:**

Support for the 2nd generation standard environment is limited, see [Python 3.7 Local Development Server Options for new app engine apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999747/python-3-7-local-development-server-options-for-new-app-engine-apps/53000831#53000831)

Comment: Do you imply that I can't simulate a local run of my application as if it was running on Google's cloud server?

Comment: Au contraire. Running your native development tools is the proper way to simulate your flex env app (this is exactly how they will run on GAE - as instructed by the `entrypoint:` config equivalent), `dev_appserver.py` only simulates the GAE standard env python sandbox in which only standard env apps run.

Comment: @DanCornilescu but how can you similate the extact sandbox if python manage.py runserver runs in local env, were you can install other stuff that are not in the app engine?, but thank you it is a good clarification the local dev env for standard apps only

Comment: @Manza Well, it's up to you to ensure you only install stuff in the local environment that you also specify as requirements for your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627798/adding-a-local-repository-for-dependency-injection-in-python-on-google-cloud/50633000#50633000

Comment: @DanCornilescu thats true, however if you have other software install for instance if you use pdfkit and you already have install wkhtmltopdf, this is going to work in your new env, but not in app engine. But yeah ill keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

Adding an updated answer (in 2022)

1. Google App Engine supports running Python 3 Apps using `dev_appserver.py` (not for Windows though)
2. Per their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/tools/local-devserver-command), ....*To run dev_appserver with a Python 3 interpreter, you must specify the `--runtime_python_path=[PATH_TO_PYTHON3_BINARY] flag`*....
3. Some of the bundled services (built-in APIs) like User, Memcache, Datastore, Namespace Manager are also now [available for Python3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access) Apps. When you enable them and use `dev_appserver.py` to run your Python3 App, you get the same behavior you're used to in Python2 i.e. you will get a simulated datastore, memcache, users, etc