# Adding a local repository for dependency injection in python on google cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, pip, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy a Python app on Google Cloud. In the app I have a dependency that is actually locally available. So to add it in project using pip. I use `pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links PATH_TO_DEPENDENCY`. Everything works fine this way on local. But when I deploy it on Google Cloud using `gcloud app deploy` it internally calls the `pip install -r requirements.txt` due to which the local dependency is not installed and the code fails.

Is there a way to modify the internal command the gcloud uses or a way to tell the server to use that dependency from somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

One option to try would be to use a virtual environment and `pip freeze` to capture all requirements for your app, including their dependencies:

- pull a fresh virtual environment and snapshot the initial package content with `pip freeze > requirements.1.txt`
- use your local invocation to install all the requirements and their dependencies, then get a new snapshot with `pip freeze > requirements.2.txt`
- build a new `requirements.txt` containing all packages present in `requirements.2.txt` but missing in `requirements.1.txt` (i.e. either from the original `requirements.txt` or a dependency)

Then use this new `requirements.txt` for your app, which *should* pull all dependencies during the deployment `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Another option, a bit more tedious but which can be used for dependencies not installable via `pip`, would be to build a custom runtime based on the corresponding google-supplied docker image in which you add the additional non-python dependencies your app require. From [About Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which might include additional components like language interpreters or application servers.

See also [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).