# Can't Upload python script on Google Cloud Console. (Error response [13] && Error response [9])

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud

I have been trying last day to deploy my script to Google Cloud console but without success!
Gcloud Version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 204.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.06.04
gsutil 4.31
```

yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.8.1
```

I tried deploying with `gcloud beta app deploy` and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-06-06 09:28:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I also have all my modules installed into a virtual env...

However, I also tried deploying with `gcloud app deploy` and I am getting a different error -> `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Error while processing files.` Referring to a similar issue which is closed now (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281) I did this command `gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True`, as the majority of people are saying that is working but for me is NOT!

Code snipet from my main.py

```
# [START app]
import logging
import sys

import firebase_admin
import moment

from datetime import datetime
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
from flask import Flask, json, make_response, render_template, request

from apiclient.discovery import build, build_from_document
from firebase import firebase
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

service_account = 'FIREBASE-ADMIN-SDK-KEY'
database_url = 'FIRABE-DB-URL'

cred = credentials.Certificate(service_account)

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': database_url
})

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(database_url, None)

user_id = ""

rootDB = db.reference()
messagesDb = rootDB.child('messages')

app = Flask(__name__)

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'Google-Serviced-Account-KEY', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

chat = build('chat', 'v1', http=http_auth, cache_discovery=False)


# Using the rest api (send message function)
@app.route('/receiver', methods=['POST'])
def message_responses():

    #Some Code here

    return 'OK'

# [END message_response]


@app.route('/getMeasages', methods=['POST'])
def get_messages():

    # Some Code here

    return 'OK'

# [END get_messages]

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def resp_get():

    event_data = request.get_json()
    print(event_data)

    return 'OK'


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home_get():    

    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END app]
```

Comment: I think you need to revisit your `requirements.txt` content: I'm fairly certain that neither `Flask` nor `gunicorn` provide `firebase_admin` - you probably have missing dependencies. Maybe try this approach to discover them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627798/adding-a-local-repository-for-dependency-injection-in-python-on-google-cloud/50633000#50633000

Comment: Thank you for the tip @DanCornilescu but still getting the same errors, even after adding all dependencies to the **requirements.txt** file

Comment: This is indeed a dependency issue. Does it work locally? You state you have all modules installed into a virtual env. I just made a quick test by doing the following:

$ virtualenv test
$ source test/bin/activate
$ pip freeze (make sure there’s nothing already installed)
$ pip install firebase_admin
Run you python script importing firebase_admin.

I also tried deploying just by adding “firebase-admin==2.11.0” into the requirements.txt file. Also no issue when deploying. If it’s still not working, could you show us the updated requirements.txt and a snippet code of main.py?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a dependency issue. I added all my dependencies to my requirements. txt file. Yes, it is running locally, I just want to host it Google cloud console. I did what you say, creating a new virtualenv test  and there were no dependencies applied to it I `pip install firebase_admin` but still getting the same errors

Comment: @VasilVasilev could you share a snippet code of main.py?

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio Ofc.. I added a section to the question you can have a look

Comment: @VasilVasilev From where i'm standing, there's not much else I can do. Your configuration looks fine and the code is correct. This must be something related to your local environment

Answer (score 0):

You are using fairly low versions of gunicorn and Flask. I would upgrade them accordingly ([google example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart)) and add firebase-admin, firebase and some other dependencies as well. Example requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
moment==0.8.2
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==3.2.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
```

I would recommend you put those dependencies in your requirements.txt file and only install from that file in a virtualenv.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```