# Running locally with GAE Python second generation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I've been using GAE/P 1st gen for many years and am making the jump to my first GAE/P 2nd gen project.

I'm trying to run it locally like I did with `dev_appserver.py` for 1st gen apps, but [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally) are very confusing in this respect.

I can run Flask on its own (`python main.py`) but static files don't work (since Flask knows nothing about `app.yaml`) and the datastore won't work either.

The GAE docs say that `dev_appserver.py` should work for 2nd gen (except on Windows but I'm on Mac) but when I run it, I get the error below.

This happens when I run `dev_appserver.py` with Python 2 or 3.  I've also set `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to my Python 2 binary as instructed.

So how the heck can I run my GAE/P 2nd gen project locally in way that static files and the datastore work?!?

---

```
$ python ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --application=myapp --support_datastore_emulator=False ./app.yaml 
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:21,885 devappserver2.py:278] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:23,128 api_server.py:275] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51187
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:23,139 instance_factory.py:71] Detected Python 3.6.5

INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:24,459 instance_factory.py:205] Using pip to install dependency libraries; pip stdout is redirected to /var/folders/yd/xr84fg0946l72fp_cc6j9l540000gr/T/tmpj3SEUZ
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:24,459 instance_factory.py:211] Running /var/folders/yd/xr84fg0946l72fp_cc6j9l540000gr/T/tmpLtysT3/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:24,469 stub_util.py:357] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2019-02-12 00:39:24,469 stub_util.py:360] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 600, in <module>
    main()
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 588, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 360, in start
    options.api_host, apiserver.port, wsgi_request_info_)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 248, in start
    ssl_port)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 384, in _create_module
    ssl_port=ssl_port)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1309, in __init__
    super(AutoScalingModule, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 598, in __init__
    self._module_configuration)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 231, in _create_instance_factory
    module_configuration=module_configuration)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/instance_factory.py", line 98, in __init__
    self._SetupVirtualenvFromConfiguration()
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/instance_factory.py", line 143, in _SetupVirtualenvFromConfiguration
    self._venv_dir, requirements_file.name)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/instance_factory.py", line 228, in _SetupVirtualenv
    cls._RunPipInstall(venv_dir, requirements_file_name)
  File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/instance_factory.py", line 212, in _RunPipInstall
    pip_proc = subprocess.Popen(pip_cmd, stdout=pip_out)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999747/python-3-7-local-development-server-options-for-new-app-engine-apps/53000831#53000831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, I was able to figure out the problem...

I was running `dev_appserver.py` from within my virtual environment.  For some reason, this prevented `dev_appserver.py` from being able to find `pip` (needed to install the packages in my `requirements.txt`).

Exiting my virtual environment before running `dev_appserver.py` fixed the problem.

Comment: Good work. I'm still on the old version, somewhat reluctant to the many breaking changes.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz, I'm upgrading one relatively simple service of a P2.7 app.  Between upgrading Python and App Engine, it is a lot of work.  Though given that P2.7 is reaching the end of its lifetime, it seems that we'll all need to do this soon...

Comment: Thanks for the information. I understand your situation. I understand that the upgrade solves a lot of problems with less hacks but I liked 2.7 and invested much time and work in it. Kind of sketchy that last time I looked I must find another solution both for memcached and for email functionality. I really like and enjoy the appengine API, since spring 2008.