# AssertionError constantly appearing when I try to use on Google App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

The following error keeps appearing whenever I try to do

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

> File "/Users/monikap/Desktop/test-dir/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 95, in 
>       **assert sys.version_info[0] == 2
>   AssertionErro**r

I have Python version 3.7 installed on my Mac

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file ?

Answer (score 0):

The development server still needs python 2 installed, even for python 3 apps, see [Python 3.7 Local Development Server Options for new app engine apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999747/python-3-7-local-development-server-options-for-new-app-engine-apps/53000831#53000831)

Answer (score 0):

[Python3 now has GA support on Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#27400_2019-12-17).

I think you need to update your Cloud SDK with `gcloud components update`.