# App Engine Python Flexible Environment Selecting A Runtime

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, runtime

I can run my app locally using
    `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

And my app works. However, when I try to deploy to app engine, I'm given the following warning: WARNING: `[runtime: python-compat]`is deprecated.  Please use `[runtime: python]` instead.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating for more info.
I tried using runtime: python, however when I do so nothing works locally. Also, when I use python-compat, I cannot deploy to app engine, I just get `Updating service [default]`. I'm using Python 2.7, what should I change to fix my runtime issues? app.yaml below

```
runtime: python-compat
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app


runtime_config:
  python_version: 2
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: Google Cloud SDK [176.0.0]

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, running the app locally through `dev_appserver.py` is only applicable to the standard environment, you were simply lucky to be able to run it (maybe because of the now deprecated `python-compat` runtime?). From [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server):

> **Note:** **`dev_appserver.py`** does not run in the App Engine flexible environment.

For the flexible environment you normally need to run your app the same way you'd run it on GAE, see [Running locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally) for details. In your case it'd be:

```
gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

With this in mind switching to `runtime: python` should no longer be an issue, you'd simply align with the official recommendations.

Side note: potentially of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)