# deploying django with gunicorn (and multiple django apps)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my first django app to google app engine but am having a hard time follow docs as many are out of date.

I have a project that I started from this (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app) but cant deploy with the outdated docs in the readme.

-I dont know my project name
-I am unfamiliar with `gunicorn` 
-and I'm unsure where to put my wsgi file as I have multiple django apps

Every tutorial seems to only have one app (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/hello_world_django)

```
# app.yaml
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

health_check:
    enable_health_check: True
    check_interval_sec: 5
    timeout_sec: 4
    unhealthy_threshold: 2
    healthy_threshold: 2

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
  expiration: '30d'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

Comment: FWIW, the shopify example is using the standard environment, you're using the flexible one - quite different beasts, don't mix them up. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or.

Comment: ok. i'll remove the `env` line.. what about entrypoint? @DanCornilescu

Comment: `entrypoint` is specific for the flex env as well - that's how you app starts. You should decide which env you actually want to use, then modify your app accordingly (reading the respective docs), then come back with specific questions. At this time it's not even clear what your problem is (apart from confusion resulted from mixing up concepts from the 2 environments).