# URL Handlers in Google App Engine PHP Flexible enviroment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have deployed a PHP project in Google App Engine as Flexible Environment, what I want is to have a custom URL so the user can press

```
www.example.com/user
```

must point to

```
www.example.com/core/userProfile/user.php
```

I have changed the `app.yaml` to be this, but I can't get it to work

```
runtime: php
env: flex
service: api 
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10

# Starting Point
runtime_config:
  document_root: '.'

# Routers
handlers:
- url: /test.php
  script: /test.php

- url: /index.php
  script: index.php

- url: /user
  script: core/userProfile/user.php
```

any url gives the following result

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /user was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.yaml` configuration is mixing up the standard environment [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) into a [flexible environment configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml), so it is probably ignored. Somehow related: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

You need to handle the URL routing **inside** your flex application, see the [Quickstart for PHP in the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart)