# Google App Engine: WARNING: The Cloud SDK no longer ships runtimes for PHP 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, php-7

I'm receiving this error when trying to deploy locally using Google App Engines's sdk (PHP 7)

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Returns

```
WARNING: The Cloud SDK no longer ships runtimes for PHP 5.4.  Please set your runtime to be "php55".
```

This is my .yaml file

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: :XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
```

It works fine using PHP 5+

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
```

My sdk components are up to date.

I'm not finding anyone having this issue. Wondering if I should just re-install the sdk.

Answer (score 3):

dev_appserver.py does not run in the App Engine flexible environment.

From the standard environment [Running the local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server#running_the_local_development_server):

> **Note: dev_appserver.py** does not run in the App Engine flexible environment.

From the flex environment [Running locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally):

> You run your application locally with the native development tools
>   that you usually use.

Comment: Excellent point, I missed the `env: flex`. Well, from several SO questions apparently the dev server doesn't mind it and attempts to run anyways. With unexpected results, of course, since it still emulates only the standard environment :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or

Answer (score 1):

The `php` option is probably still around for backward compatibility since 5.4 used to be supported. Use `php55`.

From the [August 14, 2015 - Version 1.9.25](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/release-notes#1.9.25) Release notes:

> - Development server no longer supports the "php" runtime. This will result in a Runtime Error. Please use "php55" instead.

And from the `app.yaml` [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#syntax) table:

> **runtime**
>
> Required. The name of the App Engine runtime environment used by this
>   application. To specify PHP, use php55.
>
> ```
> runtime: php55
> ```

**Update:**

The above applies to the standard environment only, but since this is a flexible environment config @btaylor507's answer is better.