# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasklets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I'm playing with GAE but I realized that when I try to start the .py file I get this error. What can I do?
Thanks

```
  python3 test.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
        from google.appengine.ext import ndb
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from tasklets import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasklets'
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`NDB` library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) is only available in the standard environment GAE, which only works with python 2.7.

So either switch to the standard environment (and python 2.7) or use the flexible environment instructions for [Using Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-datastore).

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)