# Google App Engine, serving static files

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine

I want to create similar environments for development, testing and deployment - and I am currently in the process of porting my app from compute engine to app engine.

Currently I have express serving static files through the standard method:

```
app.use(express.static('../dist'));
app.use(express.static('../public'));
```

Reading over the App Engine docs it is not very clear how to set this up correctly to work on `localhost` & web-preview they provide and finally in production.

Are the handlers within `app.yaml` necessary or can this be left to express?

Some extra clarification:

- I want to avoid `if/else` based on environment
- I want a single method of serving static files, they should be accessible via a url, but also for express to send based on route logic.

And I am using the **flexible** app engine environment.

Comment: standard or flexible env?

Comment: @DanCornilescu flexible env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `app.yaml` handlers configuration for serving static files is specific to the standard environment only, see [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files). Quite common confusion, this may help: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or).

For the flexible environment the instructions are at [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files):

> The flexible environment allows you to decide how to serve static
>   content for your application. You can serve static content directly
>   from your application, host it on a GCP option like [Cloud
>   Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), or use a third-party content delivery network (CDN).

Since you want to serve the static content from your application, your already implemented solution based on `express.static` (just as in [Example of serving static files with your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files#example_of_serving_static_files_with_your_app)) should be all you need, for all environments.