# Google App Engine Login required Flex

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I use Flex and Symfony
I want to have a url behind authentication.
I tried with

```
handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: app.php
  login: required
  secure: always
```

or

```
- url: /.*
  script: app.php
  login: admin
```

When I deploy my app, I can't login and i receive 403.
How can I have an url for deployment behind auth?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The attempts you made are only applicable to the standard environment. Maybe useful: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

The `login` and `secure` configurations are deprecated in the flexible environment. From the [app.yaml changes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/upgrading#appyaml_changes) section of the [Upgrading to the App Engine Flexible Environment Latest Release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/upgrading) guide:

> Authentication changes
>
> You must also update the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) file to remove or replace the
>   other configuration setting that have been deprecated:
>
> - **Secure handlers**
>
> The `secure` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App
>   Engine flexible environment. If you need SSL redirection, you can
>   update your application code and use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to
>   redirect `http` traffic. You can also use the [HTTP Strict Transport
>   Security response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet).
>
> - **Login handlers**
>
> The `login` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App
>   Engine flexible environment. You should follow the guidance for [User
>   service migration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#users).

Also from [Users](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating#users) section in the [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating) guide (emphasis mine):

> The Users service is not available outside of the standard
>   environment. You can use any HTTP-based authentication mechanism in
>   the flexible environment, such as:
>
> - [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/), which provides many options for authentication and authorization of Google user accounts.
> - [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which provides authentication using username/password and federated identity using Google, Facebook,
>     Twitter, and more.
> - [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), which provides authentication with various identity providers and single sign-on features.
> - [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) which provide federated identity from the provider of your choice. Google is an [OpenID
>     Connect identity provider](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect). There are also several [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect#Adoption)
>     providers available.
>
> **Note that because the Users service is not available, it is not possible to use [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref) to make URLs accessible only by
>   administrators. You will need to handle this logic within your
>   application.**

You'll note that there is no mentioning of `login`/`secure` (or `handlers` for that matter) in the flexible environment [`app.yaml` Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml) doc.

So you need to take care of the authentication inside your app code instead.

Comment: thanks, than I can't have a development env without build authentication ?