# Error while deploying python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, cgi

I am trying to deploy a python application and I am receiving the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has
>   failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled
>   back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the
>   'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: python
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
env: flex
service: newservice
handlers:
- url: /
  script: hello.py

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I believe the problem is related to the yaml file, since I have deployed a sample application previously with no problems (using entrypoint on my yaml), then when I added a new python script and referred to it on the yaml file (using the handlers, to run my message block) I started to get this error.

Edit:
after GAEFan's answer my hello has included a handler for readiness_check as:

```
def post():
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
    obj = {
      'status': 200, 
    } 
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))

webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/readiness_check', post())
], debug=True)
```

Comment: I assume you have imported both `webapp2` and `json`?

Comment: Do you see the json output when you go to `/readiness_check` locally?

Comment: What do you see in the logs?  https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running in a flexible environment app, the `handlers` configuration is a standard environment one. You need to use the `entrypoint` configuration for the flexible environment. From [Application startup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup):

> The runtime starts your application using the `entrypoint` defined in
>   [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). The entrypoint should start a process that responds
>   to HTTP requests on the port defined by the environment variable
>   `PORT`.

Without it your app is not really working and can't serve the health check requests.

Maybe useful: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I've corrected it to entrypoint: python hello.py and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

`Readiness checks` are enabled by default.  So, you should set up url handlers for them.  In this case, GAE is sending a request to `/readiness_check`, but your `app.yaml` doesn't have a handler for that url.  Try this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.py
```

And make sure the url returns a `200` or similar response.  To customize the readiness checking:

```
readiness_check:
  path: "/readiness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

Or:

```
liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
```

Details at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#legacy_health_checks

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I still did not have success. I have both url: / and url: /.* and tried it with both readiness and liveness checks. I might not have told you that my deploy keeps "Updating service" and after a long time I receive the above message, so I think I am not be able to receive the 200 status, if ii is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: in `hello.py`, do you have a url handler for `/readiness_check`?  Can you test locally?

Comment: I am new to this. Does this handler make sense? (yes, my hello works locally)

def post():
 self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
 obj = {
   'status': 200, 
 } 
 self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))

webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/readiness_check', post())
], debug=True)

Comment: I've edited my question to include my supposed handler for better read

Comment: Actually now I am receiving the error: 

"Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned."