# document_root ignored in Google App Engine with standard environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm working on a PHP app in Google App Engine. I set the document_root to "public" in the yaml, but it's ignored by the server when I deploy the app.

This is my directory structure:

```
app engine:/
- public
  - good.php
  - index.php
- app.yaml
- bad.php
- php.ini
```

And this is the contect of my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

What I expect to happen:

- When I browse https://mysiteurl, it loads the content of index.php.
- When I browse https://mysiteurl/bad.php, it shows the content of index.php (because it should not have access to the root app directory).
- When I browse https://mysiteurl/good.php, it shows the content of good.php

What actually happens:

- When I browse https://mysiteurl, it loads a blank page.
- When I browse https://mysiteurl/bad.php, it shows the content of bad.php.
- When I browse https://mysiteurl/good.php, it shows a blank page

How can I fix this? Am I missing something? Is something wrong with my document_root declaration in the yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Dan Cornilescu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51510108/4424864) pointed out. There's no such document_root directive for the standard enviroment yaml.

But I finally managed to achieve what I wanted by using the following YAML:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: public/\1

- url: /.*
  script: public/index.php
```

In this way, whatever url you browse, only things inside the "public" directory are accessed.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing flexible environment configs in your standard environment `app.yaml` file.

The `document_root` is under [`runtime_config`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#the_runtime_config_section), which is a flexible environment configuration, not a standard environment one. There is no mention of such config in the standard environment [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref).

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

In the standard environment you'll need to use the `handlers` configurations to achieve what you want.

And remember that their URL patterns are relative to the respective service's root directory which is where its `app.yaml` file exists. This is why your `bad.php` script is served OK (matching your first handler pattern). I'd also expect `https://mysiteurl/good.php` to give a 404 and `https://mysiteurl/public/good.php` to work OK (but I'm not very certain, I'm a python user, not a php one).