# Google App Engine - Error (libraries entries are only supported by the "python27" runtime)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I developed a web application based on Python 3.6 and Django 2.0 and want to deploy in Google App Engine for the first time. When I tried to deploy (`gcloud app deploy`) it, it did not go through and showed me the error message as follows:

```
(acct) C:\Users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\src>gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [C:\Users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\src\app.yaml]
libraries entries are only supported by the "python27" runtime
  in "C:\Users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\src\app.yaml", line 34, column 13
```

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: acct.wsgi.application

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: 1.2.5
```

Does not GAE support Python 3 and Django 2 yet? I looked for the answer and tried in many ways but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up [standard environment `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) config elements (`libraries` in your case) into a [flexible environment `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) configuration file, which causes the error you see.

Notes:

- the standard environment only supports python 2.7, which is where the version mentioned in the error message comes from
- depending on which such element is introduced there may be no error generated, things may be silently not working - your `handlers` configs, for example, also standard environment specific

In the flexible environment your dependencies are managed:

- via your app's `requirements.txt` file, for python dependencies, see [Using Python Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries)
- by including them in a custom runtime, for non-python dependencies, see [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build)

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

Comment: Yes, I referred to many app.yaml samples and mixed them without environment consideration. So I can go further after update, but another error occurred like this, "Failed to find application object 'app' in 'acct'". I think this issue is related to the coding, "entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT acct.wsgi" in "app.yaml" . I know this is another issue. But if you give me any clue it will be a good help. Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: do you have an `acct.py` file with an `app` variable pointing to your app? See [Application startup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup)

Comment: Mine is a django project and project name is 'acct' which has 'manage.py'. I don't know where 'app' comes from.

Comment: I didn't use django. Try `mysite.wsgi`, based on this guide: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

Comment: I think 'mysite' is a sample project name in the guide. My project name is 'acct'. Today, when I tried the same command again, it worked. I don' know why... though.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

Via https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime

Comment: Sorry, but It does not work. The same error occurred.