# Whats is the difference between http request timeout of Automatic Scaling vs flex & standard app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-flexible

I am using Google App Engine for building micro services, now we are having issue of DeadlineException for most of the time as our service is not responding withing 60 secs as it is doing many complex task as pdf file parsing n all...

Now by looking at this comparison table https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments under *"Comparing High Level Features"* -> Maximum Request Timeout, one can simply figure out that its because I am using Standard App Engine and its timeout is 60sec, If my request needs more time to respond then I can shift to Flex App Engine model.

Having said that I came across another comparison table https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed
Under *"This table compares the performance features of the three scaling types:"* -> Maximum request timeout, it also has various deadline times depending upon what scaling type you choose.

1. Now I do not understand what this deadline is now?
2. I mean If I choose Flex App Engine and then I choose Automatic Scaling then my http request time would be 60 mins or 60 sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the scenario of GAE Standard vs GAE Flex regarding timeouts is the following:

[GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling):

- Automatic scaling: 60 seconds
- Manual scaling: 24 hours
- Tasks: 10 minutes with automatic scaling, 24 hours with manual scaling

[GAE Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits_1):

- Automatic scaling: 60 minutes
- Manual scaling: 60 minutes
- [Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#top_of_page): 60 minutes

Comment: I did not get exactly what that Reserved means, can you explain it in more easier language? because when I read *Response limits* section below that it does says one hour response time, does this means it would allow 1 hour's time window to respond?

Comment: Yes. it will be 60 minutes for flex. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second documentation pointer in your post is applicable to the standard environment, not the flexible one (see [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)). The equivalent page for the flexible environment is [How Instances are Managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-instances-are-managed).

So the deadline specified in the first reference is the one applicable if you chose the flexible environment.