# Google cloud platform php application deployment using both environments(Standard & Flexible)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, app-engine-flexible

I'm able to deploy php application in google cloud by configuring app.yaml for Standard and Flexible environments separately.

**'app.yaml' For Standard Environment:**

```
 runtime: php55
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
  - url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php

  - url: /fileUpload.php
  script: fileUpload.php
```

**'app.yaml' For Flexible Environment:**

```
 runtime: php55
 env: flex  # flexible env
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
  - url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php

  - url: /fileUpload.php
  script: fileUpload.php
```

Now i want to use both environments in single application.
1. Standard environment for the URL of helloworld.php
2. Flexible environment for the URL of fileUpload.php

**so please suggest me the structure of this application. 

Thanks in Advance**

I tried with below structure but it's not working..

```
|-dispatch.yaml

|-standard

  |-app.yaml

  |-helloworld.php

|-flexible

  |-app.yaml

  |-fileUpload.php
```

**dispatch.yaml code:**

```
dispatch:
- url: "*/fileupload/*"
  service: flex-module
- url: "/.*"
  service: default
```

How to utilize both standard & flexible environments within a single application?

Example: 
Domain: example.com

1. if we access url 'example.com/' or 'example.com/helloworld.php' : then it will use the standard environment.
2. if we access url 'example.com/fileupload.php' : then it will use the flexible environment.

is it possible, to process above two conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mangu
it's single application only, not two subapps.
Example: 
Domain: example.com

1. if we access url 'example.com/' or 'example.com/helloworld.php' : then it will use the standard environment.

2. if we access url 'example.com/fileupload.php' : then it will use the flexible environment.

is it possible, to process above two conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The environments on google cloud are per app. if you want to deploy on different environments they must be separated apps or a least the same copy on different microservices. Not a single deployment for two different enviroments.

this is for the stantard environment but is the same concept https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/microservices-on-app-engine
each module or microserivice is an app by itself. beacuse it manage its own resources besides the ones being shared such the database ect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible: you'd have a single GAE application (i.e. a single GCP project) with 2 services, one standard and one flex. You pretty much started in this direction, but you missed a few things.

The runtime is incorrect and you're missing the service naming of the (non-default) `flex-module` `app.yaml`. From [General settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#general):

> **runtime: php**
>
> This setting is required. It is the name of the App Engine language
>   runtime used by this application. To specify PHP, use **php**. Other
>   runtimes are available; refer to each language's documentation for
>   more info.
>
> **service: service_name**
>
> Required if creating a service. Optional for the default service. Each
>   service and each version must have a name. A name can contain numbers,
>   letters, and hyphens. It cannot be longer than 63 characters and
>   cannot start or end with a hyphen. Choose a unique name for each
>   service and each version. Don't reuse names between services and
>   versions.

You can also drop the [standard env configs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref) in this file - they're ignored presently but just in case the check become more strict down the road). Maybe peek at the somehow related [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

```
 runtime: php
 env: flex  # flexible env
 service: flex-module
```

You should check [The runtime_config](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#the_runtime_config_section) section as well, it appears to be mandatory, but I'm not a PHP user, I don't know what to suggest here:

> You must configure `document_root` in the `runtime_config` section,
>   such as in the example above.

You need to be careful with your `dispatch.yaml` content. The pattern for the flex service doesn't match the URL you chose for that service, it needs to. You can also drop the default service pattern at the end - anything not matching the specified route patterns goes to the default service anyways.

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/fileUpload.php"
    service: flex-module
```

**Note**: I always used a directory pattern in `dispatch.yaml` - i.e. `- url: "*/some_dir/*"` - never just a specific file, I'm not 100% certain the above will work, it may need some tweaking if it doesn't.

In the default service's `app.yaml` you can drop the handler for the upload - that would be handled by `flex-module`. Just cosmetic.

Also take care at deployment - you have 3 deployables: the 2 services (deployed by deploying the respective `app.yaml` files) and the `dispatch.yaml` file which must be specifically deployed. Any combination of the 3 `.yaml` files can be included in a single deployment command (but that's just convenience, under the hood each of them is actually deployed separately):

```
gcloud app deploy standard/app.yaml flexible/app.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

Comment: please look into this one also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411030/4603948

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not a PHP user.