# Handling /_ah/start route NodeJs at Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine

I am using **Google App Engine** Standard Environment for my NodeJs App. 
Things were working fine until I register a route '/*' in my express app to catch all routes after my initial routes like '/', '/login' etc. . After deploying my app on GAE I got :

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

In my App Engine build logs :

[image]
My app.yaml looks like:
**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
service: default
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Quoting from official Docs of GAE:
**https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed**

> Startup
>   Each service instance is created in response to a start request, which is an empty HTTP GET request to /_ah/start. App Engine sends this request to bring an instance into existence; users cannot send a request to /_ah/start. Manual and basic scaling instances must respond to the start request before they can handle another request. The start request can be used for two purposes:
>
> To start a program that runs indefinitely, without accepting further
>   requests. To initialize an instance before it receives additional
>   traffic. Manual, basic, and automatically scaling instances startup
>   differently. When you start a manual scaling instance, App Engine
>   immediately sends a /_ah/start request to each instance. When you
>   start an instance of a basic scaling service, App Engine allows it to
>   accept traffic, but the /_ah/start request is not sent to an instance
>   until it receives its first user request. Multiple basic scaling
>   instances are only started as necessary, in order to handle increased
>   traffic. Automatically scaling instances do not receive any /_ah/start
>   request.
>
> When an instance responds to the /_ah/start request with an HTTP
>   status code of 200–299 or 404, it is considered to have successfully
>   started and can handle additional requests. Otherwise, App Engine
>   terminates the instance. Manual scaling instances are restarted
>   immediately, while basic scaling instances are restarted only when
>   needed for serving traffic.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem by registering my last route as this:

```
app.get(/^(?!.*_ah).*$/,(req,res,next)=>{
})
```

as compared to my previous configuration.

```
app.get('/*',(req,res,next)=>{
    })
```

Here I used **negate regex**. [Credit to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

[Quoting from official GAE Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed)

> To initialize an instance before it receives additional traffic. Manual, basic, and automatically scaling instances startup differently. When you start a manual scaling instance, App Engine immediately sends a /_ah/start request to each instance.

What above route handler does is to catch all routes except the one starting with `_ah` that means _ah/start and _ah/stop will not be listened by my app as they are used by Google App engine for registering the app.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go through the [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref), you have several configs in there which aren't supported (some are [only applicable to the flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml)) or are simply redundant in your environment and have no effect on your app:

```
env: standard
service: default
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Out of them the resources ones *might* be relevant, you seem to desire 0.5G of memory for your app. For that you'd need an `instance_class` configuration, selecting at least a `B4` class. Otherwise your app gets only a `B2` (with 256M of memory). From [Runtime and app elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements):

> *Default*: **B2** is assigned if you do not specify an instance class along with the [basic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#basic_scaling) element or the [manual_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#manual_scaling)
>   element.

But that's just a suspicion. You may want to dig out the actual error log matching the `500` err for the `/_ah/start` request, hopefully it can pinpoint the root cause of the failure (plenty of possibilities, insufficient memory is just one of them). Without it it's just guesswork.

Side note - potentially of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)

Comment: I used the hack for negating regex in my route handler for _ah routes.Although i have made recommended changes to the configuration file app.yaml .

Comment: CPU and Memory are valid parameters: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml