# Dynamic HTML Page not found in App Engine. Returns Cannot Get /index

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to host my HTML page in App Engine. When I am trying to access the webpage with url/index it returns

> Cannot GET /index

I have followed the steps mentioned in 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website
having same file structure as it expects according to the link above.

```
- my_project
 |- app.js
 |- app.yaml
 |- www
    |- index.html
```

The below is my app.yaml file

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: service_name

# Adding CORS Support
handlers:
- url: /index
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /index
  static_dir: www/

- url: /getEndPoint
  script: app.js
# [END CORS Support]
# [END app_yaml]
```

Not sure what am I missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're following the python 1st generation standard environment documentation, but your `app.yaml` selects the nodejs flexible environment (and uses statements not supported/ignored in this environment's [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml))

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or/45842773#45842773)

So you either:

- follow the nodejs flexible environment [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files) documentation
- switch to the nodejs standard environment (by dropping the `env:flex` statement and selecting the `nodejs10` or `nodejs8` runtime) and follow the corresponding [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files) documentation.

If you're unsure which environment you want, go through the [Choosing an App Engine Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) guide.

Comment: Thank you Dan. This is exactly the problem I was facing.