# Google Cloud App Engine gives Cannot Get / for the first request

Tags: http, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a perfectly fine express node.js app that serves http requests. I put it on Google Cloud App Engine.

It serves the pages fine, but occasionally when I visit the page I get a white page that says:

`Cannot Get /`

if I refresh the page is served as usual.

This happens very often for my initial requests for the website. I use a custom domain.

How can I track this error, it doesn't show up in the log viewer. What is the cause of this?

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs12

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "example-gcs-bucket"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

Comment: https://trackdailywork.com is my domain

Comment: Use the Chrome or other debugger: `Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources because their origin is not included in the content security policy header`

Comment: Found this similar [Dynamic HTML Page in App Engine. Returns Cannot Get /index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854036/) which could tell us that there could be something interesting in your app.yaml file. Can you share it with us? Just make sure to remove any sensitive information.

Comment: Also, are you using App Engine Standard or Flex?

Comment: I think Standard, with free tier, but not sure where to find that information.

Comment: No worries, if you were in Flex, the yaml file would have something like env: flex, this is Standard and we can discard issues with the yaml.

Comment: @eguneys Did you find the issue?

Comment: found a solution for my Nuxt app on appengine, happening on cold starts, it was because my server index.js was missing `await nuxt.ready()`. maybe helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing additional information on the comments, we could discard any issues with your `app.yaml` file.

It seems that App Engine fails from time to time to add the CSP headers in their responses, making the message `Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources because their origin is not included in the content security policy header` to be shown as found by John Hanley.

After some deep research it seems that this is a known issue and the GCP team is working to fix this. To mitigate this in the meantime you will need to set a policy as a HTTP header (recommended), or via an HTML `<meta>` tag following this [Public blog](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/67241/refused-to-load-the-script-https-www-gstatic-co/#Post268030).

I have created this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/176622786) for you and the community to track the GCP team's progress. It includes the steps to diagnose the issue and the current workaround

Comment: I've set the meta csp headers, but I still have this issue, please check https://trackdailywork.com and https://chessishard.com