# What can you specify in script setting of handler element in flexible environment for Google App Engine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying out flexible environment in Google App Engine using *python 3*.
However, I am figuring out what you can specify in *Handlers.script* section.

According to this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/706104284e12c18e82683b372a031018601d273c/02_ingest/monthlyupdate/app.yaml#L18), looks like you allowed to specify other than *auto* which was *only* setting you allowed to set in [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element).

So my question is in *flexible environment*, what are the **syntax** you are allowed to set?

I appreciate if I could get some clarification with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `handlers` section in the flexible environment [`app.yaml` configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml), that's only valid in the standard environment.

In the code you referenced the `handlers` configs will be ignored, the `ingestapp.app` will be executed because it is referenced in the `entrypoint` configuration:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT ingestapp:app --timeout 120
```

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or)