# Can a Google App Engine NodeJS app install separate node_modules in separate directories?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vuejs3

A similar question to [Google App Engine - Deploy different folder with the same app.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677834/google-app-engine-deploy-different-folder-with-the-same-app-yaml), but more specific.

I'm attempting to deploy a MEVN stack application using Google App Engine's (GAE) NodeJS app process.

The application has the following general structure:

```
app
   - server
      - dist
      - node_modules
      package.json
      package-lock.json
   - client
      - dist
      - node_modules
      package.json
      package-lock.json
   app.yaml
   package.json
   package-lock.json
```

In an ideal world, when I run `gcloud app deploy`, I'd like for GAE to install the production dependencies for both my `server` and `client` folders (or sub-applications).

In attempting this, I've run up against a number of obstacles:

1. GAE's file-system is read-only, so I cannot manually specify any commands to install the dependencies within each sub-folder (throws an error).
2. In the `app` directory, I have toyed around with having another `package.json` file (as you can see in the above folder structure example) that lists the `client` and `server` modules as dependencies themselves. While this works to install all the dependencies for `client` and `server`, the `node_modules` folder that is created is then located in the `app` directory and thus unable to be accessed from within `server` and `client`.

I'm sure that what I'm looking for is possible by *just having two GAE instances running simultaneously, one for `client` and the other for `server`*.

But I'd like for this to be possible with just one GAE instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated!